# CSS border issue with THEAD TBODY and COLSPAN

Tags: html, css, border, html-table, w3c

i have an issue with css/html table:
When I use *thead* and *tbody* tags with a colspan attribute, the bottom border of the header is divided.
The gap size is dependent of the *th* border width.

**Did you have a solution to get a continuous border on header bottom (without removing *thead* and *tbody*) ?**

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vingran/sspyL66L/)

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black
}

td {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

thead tr {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black
}

td {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

thead tr {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green
}
```

```html
with THEAD and TBODY but without COLSPAN
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Content 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br /> COLSPAN with THEAD and TBODY <span style="background:yellow">(css bug in the middle of green border ?)</span>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        Content 1 and 2 (merged cells)
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br /> COLSPAN without THEAD and TBODY
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Column 1
    </th>
    <th>
      Column 2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      Content 1 and 2 (merged cells)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your need means what exactly you want. Make it clear.

Comment: in what browser do you have the problem?

Comment: @rewobs I see the OP's problem in Mozilla, not in Chrome. [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3A1Wd.png). Does look like a bug. Can't find a solution or workaround.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in Mozilla. In Chrome it's OK. I need a continuous border in separating the header and the body of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corner rendering between collapsed borders does not seem well-specified, so it's not clear that this is actually a bug rather than just a variance in behaviour.

I did find a horrible workaround for Firefox, by creating a pseudo second row in the thead, and then hiding it, and also hiding the top border of the first tbody row like this:

```
thead:after {
    content:'';
    display:table-row;  /* see note below */
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}

tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top-width:0;
}
```

<sub>(Note that the `display:table-row` is just for show. In reality, the `position:absolute` causes the pseudo-element to be `display:block` regardless of whether the display property is set to `table-row` or left at its default `inline`. The table layout of the container will then cause that block to be wrapped in anonymous table objects of table-row and table-cell to form a well structured table.)</sub>

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black
}

td {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

thead tr {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green
}

table ~ table thead:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
table ~ table tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top-width:0;
}
```

```html
with THEAD and TBODY but without COLSPAN
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Content 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br /> COLSPAN with THEAD and TBODY <span style="background:yellow">(css bug in the middle of green border ?)</span>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        Content 1 and 2 (merged cells)
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br /> COLSPAN without THEAD and TBODY
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Column 1
    </th>
    <th>
      Column 2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      Content 1 and 2 (merged cells)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an illusive fix to this by changing the borders from 4px/5px to 1px. As to why you are getting that must have to deal with the properties of thead and tbody, being that the problem only occurs with their presence.

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

Comment: The vertival border size is 1px in the correct version of my site. I put 4px to to highlight the problem.
I use thead and tbody because it's needed for the javascript tablesorter script used.